# Why is gdtr in nasm not working as it should?

Tags: x86, nasm, osdev

I'm writing a operating system in NASM and i wan't to switch to protected mode but I have one problem and that is that I get a error that says:

> deos.asm:20: error: symbol `gdtr' undefined

when i write:

```
lgdt [gdtr]
```

Does anyone know why that happens

Comment: Did you define a _Global Descriptor Table_ in memory? You have to define one to point to one (by `[gdtr]`). Defining one would create the appropriate label.

Comment: How do you define the global descriptor table register then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[gdtr]` doesn't reference a register.  It's a label name that you'd have to declare in memory, holding a limit and pointer to your GDT.  Or use an addressing mode like `lgdt [edi]` instead of `lgdt [disp32]` if you have that address in a register.

The internal GDTR base/limit registers are *implicit* destination operands for `lgdt` (and source for `sgdt`); read the manual for the instruction: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lgdt:lidt

The Operation section includes this pseudo-code for LGDT:

```
        ELSE IF 32-bit Operand Size
            THEN
                GDTR(Limit) ← SRC[0:15];
                GDTR(Base) ← SRC[16:47];
            FI;
```